# Use scroll beside touchstart and touchend events in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, scroll, touch

I wanted to catch long touch event using java script so I used **touchstart and touchend** but the scroll in the application is stopped .
Is there is a way to catch long touch and keep scroll functionality working

```
var longpress;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#element").on('touchstart' ,function(){ 
  longpress=true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(longpress)
      alert("long press works!");
  }, 2000);
})

$("#element").on('touchend' ,function(){ 
   longpress=false;
})
```

Comment: it wasn't working but I found the solution I useed quo.js:[link](http://quojs.tapquo.com/)  to catch hold event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem using [quo.js](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) and here's the code after modification

```
$$('#element').hold(function(event) {
   alert('long tab detected');
}
```